Drill a hole into fiber cement siding
I’m a newbie trying to learn how to DIY.
I’m trying to drill a small hole into the fiber cement siding on the outside to route wiring from the panel shown here to the garage right behind the wall. I wonder if I need to use stud finder or if I can drill anywhere I want. Is there anything else that I should pay attention before drilling?
Also, what kind of drill bit should I use?




Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


Can now be certain from the additional pictures, that this is a meter-main panel, so there are already cables or conduits running through the wall to the inside that come out of its back, and don't take a kludgy path sideways and through the siding to get there.
That's the same way any new cable (or conduit) to the box should be run.
Drilling anywhere near an electrical panel should not be done blind. That can make for very expensive, if not fatal, results when you drill into cables in the wall.
If there are no cables into the garage yet and you're biting off a much larger DIY job by doing all the wiring after the meter-main yourself: that's still the way it's done, and you'll need some serious DIY-education to tackle the job correctly. As there isn't an access panel on the inside behind the box, it's time to make one since you have finished drywall hiding things there.

I’ve added some photo for front view of the meter and back side of the meter behind the wall. I hope it’s more clear to see


I’m trying to drill a small hole into the fiber cement siding on the outside to route wiring from the panel shown here to the garage right behind the wall.

After your clarification in comments, then the only meaningful answer to this question is - don't.
An EV charger mounted in the interior of the garage, assuming its possible to be connected to the electrical panel you showed, would not have its wiring routed through the siding.  It would be routed from a punch-out in the rear panel of the electrical panel that feeds into the interior wall - which is likely the same way the existing wiring in the panel is routed.
Drilling a hole in the siding would only be warranted if you intended to punch out of the panel from the side or bottom and then run sealed conduit back inside the house through another hole in the siding.  But that would be somewhat unsightly, IMHO - and wholly unnecessary.

Well, since you're working in the immediate vicinity of high current, unfused wiring it would be prudent to be very aware of what your drill bit will encounter. A stud finder isn't really the answer. You'll want eyes on the subject. I assume you have access to the inside of the wall for your electrical work, so start there.
Cement board siding is harsh on drill bits. A typical high-speed steel bit (or even a spade bit) will do the job, but it'll get dull in a hurry. Masonry bits would last longer, but they won't cut as cleanly. They'll tend to fuzz the surface of the siding. Whether that's a problem depends on the rest of your plan.

I also just added the photo of the wall behind the meter. Is there anything that I should pay attention before drilling?

@allennguyen - You cannot just drill.  You will need to open the wall in the area you intend to work, by carefully cutting and removing a section a of drywall, which you can later either replace or put an access panel.  Careful with the cutting - since you know there will be electrical cables somewhere, you'll have to cut no deeper than the thickness of the drywall itself.  Once you have it open and can see what is going on and can plan the conduit's route - then you can drill through the exterior wall from the inside. (a small pilot-hole bit first to find the location can be helpful)

Since it appears from the photo that you can still see the drywall tapelines and screws, another approach would be to locate and unscrew an entire panel of the drywall, then re-hang and tape it when done.

First. I worked with an electrician for many years. I have almost 40 years of contracting experience. That service panel is 200 amps. You should never be attempting a DIY project with that amount of voltage. You need to get an electrical permit. And you'll need an inspection. You need to consult with or hire an electrician to complete the project you're undertaking. Be safe, not sorry.

The voltage is exactly the same regardless of the amperage of the panel. What can and cannot be done DIY varies with the LAHJ. Yes, a permit may be required.
